# couchdb and node.js application deployment

Tags: node.js, couchdb

I am new to couchdb and node.js. In my application I will need some server side logic and a rest api for storing and querying json documents and attachments in couchdb. Moreover, the application will provide a web console using angularjs for managing data.

What would be the best scenario for this application. Following options come to mind:

- putting node.js with express in front of couchdb and serve the rest api and the console from node.js
- putting couchdb in front, serving the console from couchdb as a couchapp and redirecting the rest requests through couchdb to node.js
- running couchdb and node.js in parallel behind nginx reverse proxy serving the rest api from node.js and the application from couchdb
- running couchdb and node.js in parallel behind nginx reverse proxy serving the rest api and the console from node.js but relaying db queries directly to couchdb
- serving the console directly from nginx, relaying rest requests to node.js and db queryies to couchdb
- running node.js and couchdb in parallel serving the console from either couchdb or node.js and the rest api from node.js without any reverse proxy in front of it
- etc. etc.

Moreover, a general question arises:
 * is it advisable to put either node.js or couchdb directly to the edge without any reverse proxy or other "wall" in front of it?

Many thanks for expert input in advance!